# The usage of article 'an' in the following case

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-articles, aspiration

It is common to use

> 1a an historical event
>
> 2a an hotel

rather than

> 1b a historical event
>
> 2b a hotel

Why 'an' is used in such case?

Comment: I've never seen "an" used with the word "hotel". Kindly add references if any

Comment: @BellaSwan Yes.Such usage is also there.In this book it is mentioned https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/j4irlow0/regionalbooks/f/6/c/a-senior-english-grammar-and-composition-9-10-original-imaesfyqtqqw3w44.jpeg?q=70

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth : Thanking for your valuable editing.

Comment: The scope of grammar as is held here on ELU and by most linguists does not extend to the choice between 'a' and 'an', hence the editing out of the 'grammaticality' referencing. // I've corrected the impression that 'a hotel' and 'a historical [event]' are (1) incorrect and (2) never used by educated native users (they're common usages). // The duplicate offers explanations of the varying accepted practices. I've heard 'an' before _aspirated_ 'hotel', 'historian' etc. I believe that it's a hypercorrection, but now a third fairly common option.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  When I was studying the topic 'USAGE OF ARTICLES',I came to know about such a usage.Before that I was unaware of such usage.

Answer (score 0):

"An" is used before a vowel sound. "A" is used before a consonant sound.

The usual pronunciations of "hotel" and "historical" sound the h, so those words begin with the consonant sound [h], so it's "a hotel" and "a historical ...".

However, some people used to pronounce "hotel" with the h silent. The word is derived from a French word where the h is silent. So some people used the French pronunciation. But now it's much more common to pronounce "hotel" the English way, with a sounded h.

Google Ngrams shows that, [in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hotel%2Can+hotel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20hotel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hotel%3B%2Cc0), "a hotel" didn't overtake "an hotel" until 1931, whereas [in American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hotel%2Can+hotel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20hotel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hotel%3B%2Cc0), "a hotel" had overtaken "an hotel" by 1820. (These stats should be taken with a grain of salt, just like any Ngrams data brought to bear on a matter of spoken English; written English tends to lag spoken English.)

Why would some people say "an historical ..."? In some people's accents, the h sound is dropped in some circumstances. This is more likely to happen if the h sound is in a weak (unstressed) syllable. The first syllable of "historical" is weak, and so we get "an 'istorical". People with that accent feature might also "an 'orrific".